# How to stop navigation using the back button in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to prevent navigation to previous controller using the back button in navigation controller when a textbox is left empty in the present controller.

There where many suggestion here but few comments said of the suggestions being a private method.

Comment: can you please add some more description as not able to get your issue

Comment: although duplicate , still suggesting as a fruit of thought.  Set the self.navigationitem.leftbarbutton = nil will solve your purpose in the view controller where you want to hide the back button. Also when you want to enable jsut set the self.navigationitem.leftbarbutton to UIbarbuttonitem object created and assigned.